# next page or page 2 reset the searched value in pagination

Tags: php

I am a new user here. I am trying to create a simple pagination with search filter for a CRM system. There are five filter option for searching and displaying the records. I want 100 records per page and my filter option is working perfectly on the first page. The problem is when I am clicking on the next page or page two to display the next 100 records of the searched data then it is resetting all the filter value and showing 100 records which I can get without selecting any filter value. I am looking for a solution for this problem so that I can get the next page based on the filter value given.

Below i am giving the pagination part of my controller and view page,

```
Controller page

if (!isset($_GET['page']) or !is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
          $page = 0;
        } else {
          $page = (int)$_GET['page']; 
        } 
$customerslist = array();    
            $customers = $db->query("select cu.email, cu.notinterested, cu.version, cu.autoresponder, cu.customer_support, cu.verified, cu.verified_date, cu.customer_id, cu.customer_name, cu.address, cu.telephone_no, cu.email, cu.person_incharge, cu.designation, ct.city_name, st.state_name, emp.username from customers  as cu left join state as st on st.id = cu.state left join city as ct on ct.id = cu.city    left join tbllogin as emp on emp.employee_id = cu.customer_support
             where cu.customer_name!='' and cu.customer_support>0 and cu.company_id='".$cid."' ".$cont." ".$order_by." limit ".$page.",100");

            foreach($customers->fetchAll() as $cl) {
                $customerslist[] = $cl;
            }  



view page

        <?php
        $nextt = $page + 100;
        if ($sno > 100)
        echo '<a href="?controller=customers&action=index&cid='.$cid.'&page='.$nextt.'"><b>Next<b></a>';

        $prev = $page - 100;
        ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php
        if ($prev >= 0)
        echo '<a href="?controller=customers&action=index&cid='.$cid.'&page='.$prev.'"><b>Previous<b></a>';
        ?>
```

Comment: you need to pass all search parameter to pagination link

Comment: could you kindly explain in details?

Comment: give me list of your GET parameters in search

Comment: $customer_name = $_POST['customer_name'];
$state_id = $_POST['state_id'];
$customer_action = $_POST['customer_action'];
$customer_support = $_POST['customer_support'];
$versions = $_POST['version_id'];
$test = $_POST['test'];
$email = $_POST['emailoption'];

Answer (score 0):

First always use GET method for search form submission:

```
$customer_name = $_POST['customer_name']; 
$state_id = $_POST['state_id']; 
$customer_action = $_POST['customer_action']; 
$customer_support = $_POST['customer_support']; 
$versions = $_POST['version_id']; 
$test = $_POST['test']; 
$email = $_POST['emailoption']; 
$cid = $_POST['cid']; 

$pagination_str = '';
if($customer_name) $pagination_str .= '&customer_name='.$customer_name;
if($state_id) $pagination_str .= '&state_id='.$state_id;
if($customer_action) $pagination_str .= '&customer_action='.$customer_action;
if($customer_support) $pagination_str .= '&customer_support='.$customer_support;
if($versions) $pagination_str .= '&versions='.$versions;
if($test) $pagination_str .= '&test='.$test;
if($email) $pagination_str .= '&email='.$email;
if($cid) $pagination_str .= '&cid='.$cid;

echo '<a href="?controller=customers&action=index?page='.$nextt.$pagination_str.'"><b>Next<b></a>';
```

Comment: Also, you need to add same thing for previous page link

Comment: HI, using this code when i click on the next page it's showing "error page" results, is there anything need to do in the query?

Comment: I have just given explanation, how to use argument with pagination string. you have to modify code as per your requirement

Comment: is there anything need to do with query limit?

Comment: Oops, this is the error page.

Looks like something went wrong.

Comment: of course, you need to set limit based on page. check http://thewebsdevelopment.com/2011/10/php-paging-script/ simple pagination understanding

Comment: Are you using any standard framework like codeignitor?

Comment: after clicking the next page it's showing the "error page" message

Comment: try to set your query as per reference link